# Coin Acceptor With Python Timer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble figuring out this code. I am currently making a script in python where a it's kind of how an arcade machine works when you have 30 seconds to continue and you can insert more coins to go again. The trouble I'm having is I cant get the coins to count up while the timer counts down. Here is my code so far:

```
while True:
    start = GPIO.input(startBtn)
    input_state = GPIO.input(counterPin)
    if input_state == False:
        coins += 1
        print(str(coins) + "¢ inserted")
        time.sleep(0.09)
    if coins == 100:
        coins -= 100
        creditss += 1
        print("You currently have: " +str(creditss) + " credits")
        timer = creditss * 5
    if start == False:
        if creditss > 0:
            print("You have: " +str(timer) + " minutes to play!")
            print("Have Fun!")
            x = timer
            for i in range(x + 1):
                time.sleep(1)
                print(formatTime(x))
                x -= 1
            timer -= creditss * 5
            creditss = 0
            if timer == 0:
                pause()
                timer += 30
                print("Continue? : Insert more money to keep playing!")
                x = timer
                if input_state == False:
                    coins += 1
                    print(str(coins) + "¢ inserted")
                    time.sleep(0.09)
                else:
                    for i in range(x + 1):
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print(formatTime(x))
                        x -= 1
                if coins == 100:
                    coins -= 100
                    creditss += 1
                    print(creditss)
                if creditss > 0 & timer != 0:
                    print("Good")
                    pause()
                else:
                    print("exit")
                    os.system('/home/pi/exit.sh')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to handle coin events in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...the best help I can give you is this:

At this point you need to refactor your code.  When you get a program with more than two - three levels of nesting (you have four if statements nested) then you should be defining functions and splitting out different parts of your program into logical chunks.  This makes debugging easier, as you can drop I/O print statements to see where your script is failing.

To help you know what to split out first - look for sections where you're repeating yourself.  If you type it more than once, it deserves its own function (DRY Principle - Don't repeat yourself).

for example you have:

```
if coins == 100:
    coins -= 100
    creditss += 1
    print("You currently have: " +str(creditss) + " credits")
    timer = creditss * 5
```

and

```
if coins == 100:
    coins -= 100
    creditss += 1
    print(creditss)
```

This functionality is extremely similar and can likely be split off into a function.  The other thing you want to think about:  You only want /one/ part of the program to be able to change the number of coins so that you know when you're calling it what's happening (explicit is better than implicit).  That should be a function and anything that needs to operate it can call it.  The easier your program is to read, the easier it will be to debug.  At least until you get issues that silently fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `sleep` function stops execution, so during countdown every time you sleep you stop checking the GPIO state for a whole second and then just check it once more until sleeping again for another second. For this strategy to work you need to be checking your input very fast as to not miss a fast event. My guess is that checking once every one second is probably not enough for what you are doing.

A sightly better solution would be to not sleep and to use `time.clock()` to check when the play time has ended. So when the game starts you store the current value of `time.clock()` and after that you continue checking it until enough time has elapsed. There could still be an input which unsets and sets your input pin faster your loop can detect it so it's not bulletproof.

I don't have experience with python on raspberry-pi but a quick google search shows me there are `GPIO.add_event_detect()` and `GPIO.add_event_callback()` functions which can be set up so a callback function is called on a GPIO pin state change, which I would guess relies on interrupts so that you wouldn't miss an event. It could be a good idea to look into that.